# Value of $z$ in $\sin z=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}(1-i)$?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I'm trying to find the value of $z$ in $\sin z=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}(1-i)$.

I have tried with the equation $\sin z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}(1-i)$ but I get stuck and can't make it simpler. Is there possible to make the value much simpler?

Comment: If you make the substitution $w = e^{iz}$, then you will have $e^{-iz} = 1/w$. Start by finding $w$, and then from there you can find $z$.

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{iz}-e^{-iz}=2i\sin z=\sqrt2(1+i)$$

Now $1+i=\sqrt2\cdot e^{i\pi/4}$

On rearrangement,
$$\iff(e^{iz})^2-2\cdot e^{i\pi/4}e^{iz}-1=0$$

$$e^{iz}=\dfrac{2\cdot e^{i\pi/4}\pm\sqrt{(2\cdot e^{i\pi/4})^2+4}}2$$

$$\iff e^{i(z-\pi/4)}=1\pm\sqrt{e^{i\pi/4}+e^{-i\pi/4}}$$

Now $e^{i\pi/4}+e^{-i\pi/4}=2\cos\dfrac\pi4=\sqrt2$